# Using strcmp for Matlab mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have the following code in a matlab script :

```
if(strcmp(data.task,'taskToDo'))
    AnalogOut(1, CurrentTime)
end
```

I want to integrate this code to a *.cpp* that i already have that is used to be compiled to *.mex* file.

What would be the simple way to do this in *.mex* style?

**Update**

From [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17093207/2419003), I realized `strcmp` would work in the .cpp file. So i just needed to tweak the code a little to make it works:

```
if (!strcmp(data.task,"taskToDo")) //here data.task is a const char *
{
    AnalogOut(1, CurrentTime());
}
```

Quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C function [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare to null terminates strings.
Note that unlike Matlab the C `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings match.

Comment: Tried it before seeing your answer. It does return 0 when the strings match. I'll post the answer in my question.